Two-terms Euler-Maclaurin formula for concave functions over polytopes
This is the mirror question of another on Mathoverflow.
Let $P\subset\mathbb{R}^{n}$ be a lattice polytope (vertices are
in $\mathbb{Z}^{n}$). Set $P_{k}=P\cap k^{-1}\mathbb{Z}^{n}$ for
$k\geq1$. Given a concave function $\phi:P\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$
(continuous on $P$). My question is: whether we have two-terms Euler-Maclaurin
asymptotics
\begin{equation}
\sum_{u\in P_{k}}\phi(u)=\int_{P}\phi\ \mathrm{d}x\cdot k^{n}+\frac{1}{2}\int_{\partial P}\phi\ \mathrm{d}\sigma\cdot k^{n-1}+\mathrm{o}(k^{n-1})\ ?\label{eq:expansion}
\end{equation}
Where $\mathrm{d}x$ is Lebesgue measure and the boundary measure
$\mathrm{d}\sigma$ is defined as follows.
For each facet $F\subset\partial P$, let $A_{F}\subset\mathbb{R}^{d}$
be the affine subspace generated by $F$, then $\mathrm{d}\sigma|_{F}$
is the Lebesgue measure normalized by the lattice $A_{F}\cap\mathbb{Z}^{d}$.
For example, $P$ is the convex hull of $(0,0),(1,0),(0,2)$, then
the length (measured by $\mathrm{d}\sigma$) of the hypotenuse is
$1$ (not $\sqrt{5}$).
Remark: There are all-terms asymptotic formulas for smooth functions, such as Tatsuya Tate and Guillemin&Sternberg. For rational piecewise linear concave function, we can take the sum as counting lattice points under the graph (need to deal with the error of floor function), then Ehrhart polynomial theory can give the leading two-terms. Then a natural ideal is approximating a general concave funtion by smooth ones or rational PL ones (indexed by j). To let $j\rightarrow\infty$, we need an uniform (for j) estimate on the remainder term. I found it is difficult. So I wonder whether it is possible to prove it without via approximation? How do we use the concavity condition?
